# What is a word with the same meaning as imminent, with a positive connotation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Is there any word with the same meaning as imminent, with a positive connotation? The sentence is " This discovery has an **imminent** impact on the technology".

Is imminent itself appropriate?

Comment: Why do you feel that imminent isn't positive? It is used frequently in the phrase "imminent danger", but on its own I don't perceive it as having a negative connotation. It's just a way to say "impending" or "about to occur".

Comment: The sentence sounds strange to me. We might say that the tiger outside your window “presents an imminent danger” or that “recovery is imminent”. You _can_ say “has an imminent impact”, but I wonder if there’s a clearer way, perhaps using the future tense. Maybe something like “This discovery will soon make an impact on the technology.”

Comment: If you want something that might sound more neutral, consider _immediate_. Also, try [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/imminent). That's where I found _immediate_ – in that list of synonyms at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

Imminent does not have a positive or negative connotation, in my experience. It simply means that something is about to happen. So **imminent impact** is appropriate if you mean to say that the impact will happen within a short time, regardless of whether the impact will be positive or negative.